# Make the number of close votes easier to see in the mobile theme

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, mobile-web

With the mobile theme, the number of close votes that have been cast thus far for each of the close reasons are not very visible. For example, on my iPod, I see this:

[image: screenshot]

It would be much easier to distinguish these counts from the surrounding text if they were shown on a different background, just as is already done in the normal theme:

[image]

Comment: Freehand circle is blue, and not red ;o(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been completed. Screenshot after [Mobile Web Refresher](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234717/mobile-web-refresher):

> [image]