# Improve visibility of existing vote count in close menu

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add a background to the number of closing votes shown in the dialog for mobile users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107407/add-a-background-to-the-number-of-closing-votes-shown-in-the-dialog-for-mobile-u)

As noted in a [previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124690/close-voting-menu-broken-on-mobile-site), I find the number of existing votes in the mobile *close* menu to be very hard to distinguish from the rest of the text:
[image]

For comparison, the desktop version:
[image]