# Mobile web refresher

Tags: discussion, design, mobile-web, announcements

We are rolling out a revisited version of our mobile web sites with the following aims:

- A navigation and look-and-feel more consistent with our desktop UI in a mobile friendly way.
- Better usability
- Equal or better functionality

Since there’s a lot to do, we will be deploying this iteratively. Our current deployment contains changes to:

1. Top Bar - We have beautiful new svg icons that scale perfectly with different mobile devices
2. Nav Bar - It now sports better typography and a more visible “current section” indicator
3. Search - Each section has its own search, accessible with the magnifying glass next to the title; the search is contextual: post list searches return… posts and user list searches return … users.
4. User flair - Moved away from the “magic drawer” in the previous version, it now resides in the bubble “site switcher”
5. Main colors and typography - moved towards less saturated blues and larger, lighter fonts. The site should now appear with each platform’s preferred sans-serif form (Arial, Helvetica Neue or Droid Sans)

Here is screenshot of before and after:

[image: before after]

Send your <3 to [Pawel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/225016/pawe%c5%82-ludwiczak) and  [Jin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/147574/jin) for the most excellent design.

Feedback , bugs and suggestions while we move to the next iteration? Please mark bugs with [mobile-web](/questions/tagged/mobile-web)

Comment: Ah the blue... I love it

Comment: no love for chat?

Comment: haven't tried it yet... can i get to the front page of the site without going to the site dropdown?

Comment: `moved towards less saturated blues`?  The old one on the left is the one that looks desaturated to me

Comment: Any plans to improve the close vote dialog? It still feels like an unstyled 90s page with no thought to usability.

Comment: Please improve the "close as duplicate" dialog as well. After selecting a question, it loads the whole thread into the dialog and you have to scroll aaaaaaall the way down to find the "Vote to close" button. It's basically unusable on mobile web.

Comment: The 'beautiful new svg icons' unfortunately seem completely invisible on a stock Gingerbread browser. Is that only me?

Comment: @michal we only support the two latest versions of mobile browsers.

Comment: Still too difficult to go directly to my subscribed tags. Even in the Android app it is not possible. I actually disable the mobile web site immediately I see it and go to the full featured one.

Comment: Please keep the "tags" formatting consistent. Mobile SO should look like SO, not like MSE.

Comment: `we only support the two latest versions of mobile browsers` I guess backward compatibility is over-rated? Only the _two_ latest versions?! And after that the icons just vanish? Nice

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it's a 3 yo browser, 5 versions back, with no support for SVG. Similarly, we don't support IE6 (which is 5 versions back from current IE). This particular feature is pretty much supported by all modern mobile browsers (http://caniuse.com/#search=svg)

Comment: @Sklivvz since the [tag:featured] tag was removed, do you want bugs still posted as answers here, or as separate questions now?

Comment: Salute to @nicael, who hold moderator powerz! :D

Comment: Establishing compatibility policies based on "how many versions back" you are is ridiculous, especially now that _some_ browsers update every six weeks or so... and not all! That IE6 was only five versions back is evidence of that. If you stopped at "it's three years old" then that's a different argument and one I could arguably get behind.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit feel free to open a separate question if you want to discuss further.

Comment: @psubsee2003 separate bug reports if you ask me.

Comment: Will you implement or fix mentioned in answers?

Answer (score 30):

### 1. "Log in" and "sign up" are hardly locable, however there is enough place to place it in standard place.

> [image]
>
> [image]

### 2. Would be good to show tag description.

> [image]

### 3. If you already added an answer, "Your answer" should be hidden, only "Add another answer" should be shown, like on the full site.

> [image]

### 4. Badge circle is misaligned, I would move it a little lower:

> [image]

### 5. Can I have ability to group rep events on one post?

> [image]

### 6. Should be "downvote" instead of "downvoted" and vice-versa, and "upvote" instead of "upvoted".

> [image]

### 7. Should be shown how much rep I earned each day.

> [image]

### 8. close 3? A bit confusing.

> [image]

#### Should be close (3), as on full site.

> [image]

### 9. When I click on "chat" link, it links me to the full site chat. Maybe make mobile chat?

> [image]

### 10. I can't see full user card if he has plenty of badges and rep:

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: The login/signup link suggestion is solid. Not sure why those got removed from the top bar.

Comment: @AnnaLear, I had the same problem and I think only the Login/Signup buttons should be noticed for editing the layout. Other things are not a problem in the Layout. Otherwise I like the new one. :) +1

Comment: I  disagree there is plenty of space. I only have a 360x640 screen. Granted, it's a dinosaur, but given its durability, I'll probably keep it for a while longer...

Comment: all of this is important

Comment: @NewAlexandria Oh, I reached the rep cap. :D

Comment: `1. "Log in" and "sign up" are hardly locable, however there is enough place to place it in standard place.` Epicx

Comment: Also an edit button for your profile.

Answer (score 21):

Looks really nice!

Two things bothered me right away though.

1. **I couldn't find search**. This is probably just something that takes getting used to, but until I read this post I was hunting through the menus in vain looking for it; I actually thought it might have been forgotten! The consistent, context-sensitive search is a marked improvement over the old placement, but... Maybe make that icon a bit bigger / darker?
2. **Getting to/from meta is harder than it needs to be**. This caught me off-guard a bit:

   [image: getting to/from meta is a really small target]

   I now have two big hit-targets (one always available) to get back to the homepage of the site I happen to be on. That's nice - I wish the mobile app had at least one of those. But getting to/from *meta* means clicking a tiny little link right next to one of those big fat targets. That's not so nice; in fact, it's worse than just using the full desktop UI on mobile and zooming in a bit:

   [image: full UI on mobile]

   Realistically, anywhere I have to target closely-spaced one-word links is gonna be irritating; the action links below each post are bad enough in this regard, but I'm not using those as much while reading<sup>*</sup> - and *most* of those don't take me to a different page.

<sup>*<sub>if I'm doing more than reading, there's a pretty good chance I'm not using the mobile theme at all, even if I am using my phone.</sub></sup>

Comment: You have a lot of notifications Shog.

Comment: Thanks to you, I now have *one more.*

Comment: @Dgrin91 Those are flags, not notifications. Also, why is your diamond green Shog?

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin Look at the notification bar on his phone.

Comment: @hichris yikes! (The sick diamond still applies :P)

Answer (score 12):

On [Stack Overflow em Português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com), there isn't enough room for all items in the nav bar.

On the left picture, the *Ask* link ("Perguntar") is missing. I believe it's actually under search, because on a question page it's visible under the title (right picture):

[image]

#### Proposed solution

The nav bar could scroll sideways, but then *Ask* would default to offscreen. A better solution: remove *Badges* ("Medalhas"). It isn't that important on mobile, there could be a link to that page somewhere else.

Comment: Removing the "Boa noite" doesn't help? ;-)

Comment: I *knew* someone was gonna notice that! :)

Answer (score 10):

Overall I like it; but I am still  having a problem seeing how to arrange the questions by newest.

Comment: I have to go add the "/questions" manually. A pain.

Comment: I've actually [found that it partially works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234787/182513).  Clicking on "Questions" will take you to `/questions` except when you are on the front page.

Comment: Ok, yeah - this is really annoying. It works fine everywhere *except* for the home page, where - as psubsee points out - clicking "Questions" does NOTHING.

Comment: Also [reported as a bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235217/) separately.

Answer (score 9):

please consider make it *live tile enabled* for Windows 8.1 / Windows Phone 8.1.

It will look amazing and will provide information at glance. Like the guys from TheVerge.com did on its site. Below you can see both tiles, from SO and theirs:

[image]

You own it to us since you still didn't provide an official app ;)

[Make a Windows 8.1/Windows Phone 8.1 Pinned Live Tile For your Website in minutes](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakeAWindows81PinnedLiveTileForYOURWebsiteInMinutes.aspx)

Comment: "they" don't owe "us" anything... this is all free

Comment: @Greg: We're feeding them reams and reams of free expert content that translates directly into advertising revenue. It is _not_ free.

Comment: @Greg Sorry, I think I didn't make myself clear enough. I meant "us" Windows Phone users since they created a native app for iOS and Android and leave "us" just with this site.

Answer (score 9):

I want to like it—really I do. And there is a lot to like. However it took just a few seconds to realize my longest standing issue with the mobile web interface has still not been addressed:

**[Moderator flag notifications should reach mobile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111212/145951)**

I was hopeful for a second when I saw the diamond, but that only shows notifications about meta posts and mod-message replies. What I really need is a flag count there next to in as on main. Even if the actual flag processing page does not get a mobile makeover, the fact that there are outstanding flags should be shown.

Answer (score 7):

The new mod tool integration is **amazing**. Thank you SO much for this.

[image: AWESOMENESS]

I have just one small complaint, though: Deleted comments are kind of cumbersome to work with.

1. The only way to see them is through the "mod -> show n deleted comments" thingy, and this redirects you to a non-mobile site. (I also can't see any way to undelete comments from this page.)

   - A great way to fix this would be to put the handy-dandy deleted comments / flags box at the bottom of the post, if it applies. (I'm referring to the one that usually appears to the left side of the post on the full site.)
2. The fancy quick comment deletion gizmo that disables the prompt box for "really delete this comment?" doesn't work. This makes it really tedious to delete multiple comments in succession.

Comment: We'll be making design tweaks to mobile mod tools in future updates. They can definitely be improved.

Comment: @Jin this comment will autodestruct in 5 seconds.

Comment: @Sklivvz That's quite a long 5 seconds you've got there

Answer (score 2):

It is really nice, I generally like Facebook-ish designs. Anyway one little annoying thing, you can not navigate between the three icons (reputation, messages and SE) directly, for example, if you open the reputation menu and then click on the messages (inbox) menu it will not open and the main page will show, you will have to click again.

Comment: I can't repro this on iPhone. What mobile OS and browser are you using?

Comment: @jin I have WP 8.1 and IE11 Mobile

Answer (score 2):

To expand on [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234726/182513), there appears to be a bug in loading the front page and `/questions` page.

When you are on **any page other** than the front page and `/questions`, clicking on the site name in the header takes you to the front page, and clicking on the "Questions" button.  This behaves exactly as expected.

But when you are already on the front page or the `/questions`, clicking on both the site name in the header and the "Questions" button takes you to the front page.  Clicking on "Questions" should take you to `/questions` but it does not and there is no way to get to that page unless you navigate away from the front page and then click "Questions".

To illustrate it better:

1. From the mobile view start on any question, for example [Mobile web refresher](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234717/mobile-web-refresher)
2. Click on the site name in the top bar.  You will be on the front page.
3. Go back to any question ([Mobile web refresher](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234717/mobile-web-refresher))
4. Click on "Questions" in the top bar
5. You will be on the `/questions` page of the site
6. Click back on the site name in the top bar, you will be on the front page
7. Click back on "Questions" in the top bar, you are **still** on the front page.  This should go back to the `/questions` page of the site.

Comment: Would be good if this question remained featured... Why don't they want it?..

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?  If the issue is not reproducible, it would be helpful to know why.  Maybe the issue is localized to a specific browser, or maybe I missed something in the steps to reproduce.

Comment: Repro. +1. Not sure about downvotes. And actually algorithm is much simpler. 1. Go to the frontpage. 2. Tap questions. You are still on the fronpage.

Comment: @nicael I know, but I was trying to show it still worked when you were on other pages