# No search field on user's profile page in new mobile web

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web

With the [new mobile web version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234717/mobile-web-refresher) of the Stack Exchange sites, there is no search field on a user's profile page anymore (or may be I just cannot find it):

[image]

This search field was very convenient to search for answers of a particular
user.

Also I could not find how to switch between "main user" and "meta user", but I am not sure if that was possible with the previous mobile web version.

Comment: There is also no site search field on most pages.