# The new mobile theme seems to think the Questions page is the same as the homepage

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, hyperlinks, mobile-web

Ever since the new mobile design pushed out, it seems to think that the Questions page (located at /questions) is the same as the homepage (located at /). The tab is highlighted as if I was there, and clicking it continues to take me back to the homepage.

The Questions page *does* exist on mobile. I can see it if I manually type /questions into the address bar. While on that page, the Questions tab correctly takes me back to that tab.

These two pages are very different pages. The homepage shows me recently active questions, whereas the Questions page only shows recently asked (new) questions.

We can always get back to the homepage by clicking on the title, so the Questions tab itself should definitely take us to the actual Questions page and not the homepage. As of now, there is no direct way to access the Questions page without manually changing the URL.

Comment: [Already mentioned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234787/259214).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two bugs here:

- "Questions" should not be highlighted on the home page
- The "Questions" link should always point to `/questions`

Both have been fixed and committed, they will be out as soon as I merge the mobile branch.

Thanks for pointing them out.

Comment: So status-completed?

Comment: @ShadowWizard once it's merged in I guess.